# Postgres: split string to separate columns using numbers as delimiters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was given a Postgres data set with about 2000 rows and one of the columns is a string of years and maintenance activity done in those years like this:

```
id        maintenance
1         2012- Filled holes, Painted, 2017- Nailed
3         2018- Booger removal
2         2012- Painted, 2017- Filled holes, 2018- Wallpaper
```

I'm trying to find a way to separate this data into columns structured like this:

```
id    year_1    year_1_maint             year_2    year_2_maint...

1     2012      Filled holes, Painted    2017      Nailed
2     2018      Booger removal
```

I'm thinking one possible solution uses something like the following (except this removes the year since it's used as the delimiter):

```
select regexp_split_to_array(maintenance, '\d{4}') 
from maintenance_database 
where maintenance is not null;
```

I can find how many columns I'll need using something like this:

```
select max(array_length(regexp_split_to_array(maintenance, '\d{4}'),1)) 
from maintenance_database 
where maintenance is not null;
```

But this is where I'm getting stuck trying to get a series of update queries or a single query that formats the data how I want.

Answer (score 0):

the first idea coming is appending "special" character to year to use it as delimiter:

```
db=# with maintenance_database(maintenance) as (values('2012- Painted, 2017- Filled holes, 2018- Wallpaper'))
select regexp_split_to_array(regexp_replace(maintenance, '(\d{4})', '\1'||chr(1),'g'),chr(1)) from maintenance_database;
                     regexp_split_to_array
---------------------------------------------------------------
 {2012,"- Painted, 2017","- Filled holes, 2018","- Wallpaper"}
(1 row)
```

here I "prepare" maintenance with `regexp_replace(maintenance, '(\d{4})', '\1'||chr(1),'g')` to be:

```
db=# with maintenance_database(maintenance) as (values('2012- Painted, 2017- Filled holes, 2018- Wallpaper'))
select regexp_replace(maintenance, '(\d{4})', '\1'||chr(1),'g') from maintenance_database;
                         regexp_replace
----------------------------------------------------------------
 2012\x01- Painted, 2017\x01- Filled holes, 2018\x01- Wallpaper
(1 row)
```

further your code used...

naturally to use year as value, you need to prepend with artificial delimiter as well:

```
db=# with maintenance_database(maintenance) as (values('2012- Painted, 2017- Filled holes, 2018- Wallpaper'))
select regexp_split_to_array(regexp_replace(maintenance, '(\d{4})', chr(1)||'\1'||chr(1),'g'),chr(1)) from maintenance_database;
                       regexp_split_to_array
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"",2012,"- Painted, ",2017,"- Filled holes, ",2018,"- Wallpaper"}
(1 row)
```